# Put adjacent elements in List into Tuples

Tags: haskell, purescript

Given a List of elements:

```
xs = [a, b, c, d, ... z]
```

where `a, b, c` etc are placeholders for arbitrary values.
I want to implement a function `adjacents :: [a] -> [(a, a)]` that produces

```
adjacentValues = [(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), ... (y, z)]
```

---

In Haskell, a recursive definition is reasonably concise:

```
adjacents :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
adjacents (x:xs) = (x, head xs) : adjacents xs
adjacents [] = []
```

Purescript is a little more verbose:

```
adjacents :: forall a. List a -> List (Tuple a a)
adjacents list = case uncons list of 
    Nothing -> []
    Just {head: x, tail: xs} -> case head xs of
                                     Just next -> Tuple x next : adjacents xs
                                     Nothing -> []
```

Is there a way to express `adjacents` without explicit recursion (using a fold)?

---

Disclaimer: This question has both Purescript and Haskell tags because I want to open it to a broader audience. I reckon an answer not to depend on haskells lazy-evaluation semantics, and therefore to be valid in both languages.

Comment: `fromMaybe empty (tail list)` (which might be spelled in Haskell as `maybe [] snd (uncons list)`) is equivalent to `drop 1 list`.

Comment: Yes, obviously true, once one thinks about it. Also more readable, thanks!

Comment: By the way, l suggest you move your solution to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, without explicit recursion, you can zip a list with its tail.

```
   let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

   a `zip` tail a

   => [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,0)]
```

Comment: This can also be written point-free as `adjacent = zip <*> tail` using the `Applicative` instance for `(->)`—`f <*> g` = `\x -> f x (g x)`.

Comment: `tail` crashes on empty lists. ``a `zip` drop 1 a`` is one way of avoiding that.

Comment: yes, and whole expression works because lazy haskell doesn't evaluate second argument of zip when first list is empty

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk Indeed. (I sometimes fail to notice such things due to an inclination to pretend `head` and `tail` don't exist.)

Comment: @duplode, I wish `tail` were just shorthand for `drop 1`. Is there a reason for it not to be?

Comment: @dfeuer If `tail` were ever made safe, relegating the "historical reasons" to history, I guess it would become `[a] -> Maybe [a]`, as in Purescript, for the sake of symmetry with `listToMaybe`. (`drop 1` would remain useful, though... I wonder if there is a nice, short name that we might give it.)

Comment: @duplode, there's also a long history of saturating subtraction, so I don't see an inherent problem with `tail [] = []`, which is almost backwards compatible. `head` is another story.

Comment: @dfeuer You have a point in that being almost backwards compatible makes the change more plausible. On another note, I now almost feel like suggesting `tailSat` as a name -- to my ears, it sounds less ad hoc than e.g. *safe*'s `tailSafe`. I guess it wouldn't become a popular suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

Purescript solution for completeness sake:

```
adjacent :: forall n. List n -> List (Tuple n n)
adjacent list = zip list $ fromMaybe empty $ tail list
```

can be expressed more elegantly as:

```
adjacent :: forall n. List n -> List (Tuple n n)
adjacent list = zip list $ drop 1 list
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of illustration (the `zip`-based solutions are definitely nicer), here is your explicitly recursive Haskell solution written as an unfold. I have golfed it into an one-liner for no particular reason.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Data.List (unfoldr)

adjacent :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
adjacent = unfoldr (\case { x:y:ys -> Just ((x, y), ys); _ -> Nothing })
```

(Note that the pattern matches here handle lists with an odd number of elements without crashing.)

Answer (score 0):

Since we've seen `zip` and `unfoldr`, we should have one using `foldr`:

```
adjacent :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
adjacent xs = foldr go (const []) xs Nothing
  where
    go a r Nothing = r (Just a)
    go a r (Just prev) = (prev, a) : r (Just a)
```

And now, because every toy problem deserves an over-engineered solution, here's what you could use to get double-sided list fusion:

```
import GHC.Exts (build)

adjacent :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
adjacent xs = build $ \c nil ->
  let
    go a r Nothing = r (Just a)
    go a r (Just prev) = (prev, a) `c` r (Just a)
  in foldr go (const nil) xs Nothing
{-# INLINE adjacent #-}
```

Answer (score 0):

folding with state, where the state is the last paired item:

in Haskell:

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

adjacents :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
adjacents [] = []
adjacents (x:xs) = snd $ mapAccumL op x xs
    where
        op x y = (y, (x,y))
```